# JodaTime with JPA, PostgreSQL and NULL values

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, jodatime

I'm trying to persists JodaTime DateTime fields with JPA to PostgreSQL but run into troubles with null pointers to database NULL values.

I'm working with the NetBeans 7 beta 2 IDE. The persistence implementation is EclipseLink 2.2.0 and I'm using an EclipseLink Converter to get the mapping to work. Here is the declaration of my field:

```
@Converter(
    name="dateTimeConverter",
    converterClass=ejb.util.DateTimeConverter.class
)
@Column(columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
@Convert("dateTimeConverter")
private DateTime testdate;
```

The converter class:

```
public class DateTimeConverter implements Converter {

    private Logger log;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object convertObjectValueToDataValue(Object o, Session sn) {
        if (o == null) {
            log.info("convertObjectValueToDataValue returning null");
            return null;
        }
        return ((DateTime)o).toDate();
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertDataValueToObjectValue(Object o, Session sn) {
        if (o == null) {
            log.info("convertDataValueToObjectValue returning null");
            return null;
        }
        return new DateTime(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(DatabaseMapping dm, Session sn) {
        log = Logger.getLogger("ejb.util.DateTimeConverter");
    }

}
```

This works fine as long as there is an actual DateTime set. But as soon as it is not set EclipseLink seems to assume a string type and postgresql starts complaining about the value being of the type character varying. I assume this is because the converter class is returning a null pointer instead of a date object and EclipseLink falls back on a default.

Is there a way to get this to work short of switching to plain java.util.Date?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `@Temporal` annotation to the `private DateTime testdate` field?

Comment: Yes but when I deploy, EclipseLink actually logs a message that it will ignore the @Temporal annotation because of the converter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a `@Converter` is used, EclipseLink does not know the type, so you need to initialize it.

In your `initialize(DatabaseMapping dm, Session sn)` method you need to set the type,

```
dm.setFieldClassification(java.sql.Date.class);
// or, dm.setFieldClassification(java.sql.Timestamp.class);
```

Comment: Pity, setFieldClassification method doesn't exists according to netbeans and the docs, i'm using 2.2.0. There is a getter with that name. Would have been a nice solution.

Comment: Found it, it's defined on the subclass AbstractDirectMapping. So after checking the type and casting it, it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This article: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/ gave me some pretty useful info on persisting the localdate to the db and it had some important differences from your DateTimeConverter implementation (specifically implementing AttributeConverter not just converter and the annotation of 'Converter' is at the class level

Comment: Thank you, looks good, you might want to incorporate a little more details and or an example in your answer because as your answer now stands it might be flagged as a link only answer. BTW the solution in the article requires JPA2.1 which didn't exist when I originally posted the question.

Comment: I wasn't sure of the 'etiquette' of copy/pasting from the source i.e. linking to it vs sharing it in its entirety here. I didn't mean to imply your solution was wrong (it was asked almost 5 yrs ago! :)). I just wanted to add this additional bit of info here for others who started off in the right direction from comments here and then needed additional help.

Answer (score 0):

We have used a different approach.
   (and apologies for our coding standards!)

In the POJO we have:

```
@Column(name="LAST_UPDATED")
  @Type(type="DateTime")
  @NotNull
  public LastUpdType getLastUpdated()
  {
    return mLastUpdated;
  }
```

In package.info we have:

```
@TypeDefs(
  { 
    @TypeDef(name = "DateTime", typeClass = JodaDateTimeType.class)
  })
```

We then have the class JodaDateTimeType

```
package uk.co.foo.hibernateutils.type;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Types;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;


public class JodaDateTimeType implements UserType
{
  private Logger mLogger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

  /**
   * Implementation taken from org.hibernate.type.MutableType via
   * org.hibernate.type.CalendarType.
   * @return true if the field is mutable, false otherwise.
   *
   * @see org.hibernate.type.Type#isMutable()
   */
  public boolean isMutable()
  {
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @param aRs A JDBC result set
   * @param aNames The column names
   * @param aOwner The containing entity
   * @return The retrieved value.
   * @throws HibernateException If a HibernateException occurs.
   * @throws SQLException If a SQLException occurs.
   *
   * @see org.hibernate.usertype.UserType
   *      #nullSafeGet(java.sql.ResultSet, java.lang.String[],
   *                   java.lang.Object)
   */
  public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet aRs, String[] aNames, Object aOwner)
      throws HibernateException, SQLException
  {
    return nullSafeGet(aRs, aNames[0]);
  }

  /**
   * Implementation taken mainly from org.hibernate.type.NullableType.
   *
   * @param aRs The resultset containing db data.
   * @param aName The name of the required value.
   * @return The retrieved value.
   * @throws HibernateException If a HibernateException occurs.
   * @throws SQLException If a SQLException occurs.
   */
  public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet aRs, String aName)
      throws HibernateException, SQLException
  {
    try
    {
      Object value = get(aRs, aName);
      if (value == null || aRs.wasNull())
      {
        if (mLogger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
          mLogger.debug("returning null as column: " + aName);
        }
        return null;
      }
      else if (mLogger.isDebugEnabled())

      {
        mLogger
            .debug("returning '" + toString(value) + "' as column: " + aName);
      }
      return value;

    }
    catch (RuntimeException re)
    {
      mLogger.info("could not read column value from result set: " + aName
        + "; " + re.getMessage());
      throw re;
    }
    catch (SQLException se)
    {
      mLogger.info("could not read column value from result set: " + aName
        + "; " + se.getMessage());
      throw se;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Implementation mainly taken from org.hibernate.type.CalendarType.
   *
   * @param aRs The resultset containing db data.
   * @param aName The name of the required value.
   * @return The retrieved value.
   * @throws HibernateException If a HibernateException occurs.
   * @throws SQLException If a SQLException occurs.
   */
  protected Object get(ResultSet aRs, String aName) throws HibernateException,
      SQLException
  {
    Timestamp ts = aRs.getTimestamp(aName);
    if (ts != null)
    {
      DateTime dateTime;
      if (Environment.jvmHasTimestampBug())
      {
        dateTime = new DateTime(ts.getTime() + ts.getNanos() / 1000000);
      }
      else
      {
        dateTime = new DateTime(ts.getTime());
      }
      return dateTime;
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Implementation taken mainly from org.hibernate.type.NullableType.
   *
   * @param aSt A JDBC prepared statement
   * @param aValue The object to write
   * @param aIndex Statement parameter index
   * @throws HibernateException If a HibernateException occurs.
   * @throws SQLException If a SQLException occurs.
   */
  public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement aSt, Object aValue, int aIndex)
      throws HibernateException, SQLException
  {
    try
    {
      if (aValue == null)
      {
        if (mLogger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
          mLogger.debug("binding null to parameter: " + aIndex);
        }

        aSt.setNull(aIndex, sqlType());
      }
      else
      {
        if (mLogger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
          mLogger.debug("binding '" + toString(aValue) + "' to parameter: "
            + aIndex);
        }

        set(aSt, aValue, aIndex);
      }
    }
    catch (RuntimeException re)
    {
      mLogger.info("could not bind value '" + nullSafeToString(aValue)
        + "' to parameter: " + aIndex + "; " + re.getMessage());
      throw re;
    }
    catch (SQLException se)
    {
      mLogger.info("could not bind value '" + nullSafeToString(aValue)
        + "' to parameter: " + aIndex + "; " + se.getMessage());
      throw se;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Implementation mainly taken from org.hibernate.type.CalendarType.
   *
   * @param aSt A JDBC prepared statement
   * @param aValue The object to write
   * @param aIndex Statement parameter index
   * @throws HibernateException If a HibernateException occurs.
   * @throws SQLException If a SQLException occurs.
   */
  protected void set(PreparedStatement aSt, Object aValue, int aIndex)
      throws HibernateException, SQLException
  {
    aSt.setTimestamp(aIndex, new Timestamp(((DateTime) aValue).getMillis()));
  }

  /**
   * Implementation mainly taken from org.hibernate.type.NullableType. A
   * null-safe version of {@link #toString(Object)}. Specifically we are
   * worried about null safeness in regards to the incoming value parameter, not
   * the return.
   *
   * @param aValue The value to convert to a string representation; may be null.
   * @return The string representation; may be null.
   * @throws HibernateException Thrown by {@link #toString(Object)}, which this
   *           calls.
   */
  private String nullSafeToString(Object aValue) throws HibernateException
  {
    if (aValue != null)
    {
      return toString(aValue);
    }

    return null;
  }

  /**
   * @param aValue value of the correct type.
   * @return A string representation of the given value.
   * @throws HibernateException If a HibernateException occurs.
   */
  private String toString(Object aValue) throws HibernateException
  {
    return ((DateTime) aValue).toString();
  }

  /**
   *
   * @return Types.DATE
   */
  private int sqlType()
  {
    return Types.TIMESTAMP;
  }

  /**
   * @return The class returned by nullSafeGet.
   * @see org.hibernate.usertype.UserType#returnedClass()
   */
  public Class<?> returnedClass()
  {
    return DateTime.class;
  }

  /**
   * @param aX First object of type returned by returnedClass.
   * @param aY Second object of type returned by returnedClass.
   * @return True if the objects are equal, false otherwise.
   * @see org.hibernate.usertype.UserType
   *      #equals(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
   * @throws HibernateException to conform to superclass signature
   */
  public boolean equals(Object aX, Object aY) throws HibernateException
  {
    if (aX == null)
    {
      return aY == null;
    }

    return aX.equals(aY);
  }

  /**
   * @param aX Object of type returned by returnedClass.
   * @return Hashcode of given object.
   * @see org.hibernate.usertype.UserType#hashCode(java.lang.Object)
   * @throws HibernateException to conform to superclass signature
   */
  public int hashCode(Object aX) throws HibernateException
  {
    if (aX == null)
    {
      return -1;
    }

    return aX.hashCode();
  }

  /**
   * @return The sql typecodes.
   * @see org.hibernate.usertype.UserType#sqlTypes()
   */
  public int[] sqlTypes()
  {
    return new int[] {sqlType()};
  }

  /**
   * Implementation taken from
   * org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.AbstractLobType.
   * @param aCached The object to be cached.
   * @param aOwner The owner of the cached object.
   * @return A reconstructed object from the cachable representation.
   * @throws HibernateException If a HibernateException occurs.
   *
   * @see org.hibernate.usertype.UserType
   *      #assemble(java.io.Serializable, java.lang.Object)
   */
  public Object assemble(Serializable aCached, Object aOwner)
      throws HibernateException
  {
    return aCached;
  }

  /**
   * @param aValue the object to be cloned, which may be null.
   * @return A copy of the given object.
   * @see org.hibernate.usertype.UserType#deepCopy(java.lang.Object)
   * @throws HibernateException to conform to superclass signature
   */
  public Object deepCopy(Object aValue) throws HibernateException
  {
    if (aValue != null)
    {
      return new DateTime(((DateTime) aValue).getMillis());
    }

    return null;

  }

  /**
   * Implementation taken from
   * org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.AbstractLobType.
   * @param aValue The object to be cached.
   * @return A cachable representation of the object.
   *
   * @see org.hibernate.usertype.UserType#disassemble(java.lang.Object)
   * @throws HibernateException to conform to superclass signature
   */
  public Serializable disassemble(Object aValue) throws HibernateException
  {
    return (Serializable) aValue;
  }

  /**
   * Implementation taken from
   * org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.AbstractLobType.
   * @param aOriginal The value from the detached entity being merged
   * @param aTarget The value in the managed entity
   * @param aOwner The owner of the cached object.
   * @return The value to be merged
   *
   * @see org.hibernate.usertype.UserType
   *      #replace(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
   * @throws HibernateException to conform to superclass signature
   */
  public Object replace(Object aOriginal, Object aTarget, Object aOwner)
      throws HibernateException
  {
    return aOriginal;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using Hibernate is a bit far out of my way but I'll keep it in mind. Thx

Comment: Why write your own type? There's http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html