# Using PostgreSQL ltree type with a Java ORM layer

Tags: java, postgresql, persistence

I like to use [`ltree`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ltree.html) from PostgreSQL contrib in one of my projects, and i like to use some kind of ORM layer (Hibernate, EclipseLink) on top of the database. I didn't find anything useful about using this type with persistence. I guess i have to extend the current PostgreSQL dialect with a new type and the corresponding operators. However i don't really know where to start and what is the correct way to do this. `ltree` works very much like a string so guess i should start form a string representation.

Can somebody give me suggestions and/or links to examples which are doing similar things? I couldn't find a complete tutorial yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here some pointers that may help you. It is not a complete answer but it is a bit too much for a comment.

Both Hibernate and EclipseLink implement the JPA standard but also have some extensions of their own and allow for custom behavior.

I haven't done anywork with ltree's in specific but I think you could just use the java String class and add an annotation to the column to overrule the normal column type used (this can be done in standard JPA).

```
@Column(columnDefinition="ltree")
private String myLtreeValue;
```

If a String an the Java side is not sufficient you can create your own class and write a converter class for it. You can see an example of that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209943/jodatime-with-jpa-postgresql-and-null-values). This would be persistence provider dependent.

When performing queries with conditions involving ltree values you would probably be best of using the JPA @NamedNativeQuery annotation to define queries involving the special operators. For an example [see here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/UsingNamedNativeQuery.htm)

Comment: Thank you, looks promising. Sadly we decided to drop ORM away because the lack of time, so i can try this out later. I gave it an up.

Comment: We used Spring's SQL row mapper in our solution. It's not actually an ORM layer but we only have a few tables so it's still very maintable.

Because i don't have time to test it, and your's is the only related answer here, i accept it.

Answer (score 9):

this:

```
@Column(name = "dir", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "ltree")
@Type(type = "ru.zen0n.hibernate.types.LTreeType")
private String path;
```

and this:

```
package ru.zen0n.hibernate.types;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public class LTreeType implements UserType {

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return  new int[] {Types.OTHER};
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        return rs.getString(names[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        st.setObject(index, value, Types.OTHER);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return new String((String)value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable)value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return deepCopy(original);
    }

}
```

Comment: With Hibernate 5.2.16, the nullSafeGet method signatures are changed as below **Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException;** . **void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException;**